# How can I pass a custom widget into another custom widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, enums, widget, final

I am trying to pass a custom made container (with background color, title, and onPressed properties) into another custom widget that creates a row of three of these containers. The goal is to be able to input titles for each of these buttons in the second widget like so, TriButton(title1, title2, title3). Any tips or tricks would be appreciated!

Custom container

```
class RectButton extends StatelessWidget {
  RectButton({this.buttonChild, this.bgColor, this.onPress});

  final Widget buttonChild;
  final Color bgColor;
  final Function onPress;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: onPress,
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(width: 100, height: 50),
        child: Center(child: buttonChild),
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: bgColor,
            shape: BoxShape.rectangle,
            border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.white)),
        padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(12, 12, 12, 12),
      ),
    );
  }
}

`Tri-button code`

enum Weight {
  ideal,
  actual,
  adjusted,
}

class TriButton extends StatefulWidget {
  TriButton({this.title1, this.title2, this.title3, this.buttonChild});

  final Text title1;
  final Text title2;
  final Text title3;
  final RectButton buttonChild;

  @override
  _TriButtonState createState() => _TriButtonState();
}

class _TriButtonState extends State<TriButton> {
  Weight selectedWeight;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Container(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(maxWidth: 300),
        child: Row(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: RectButton(
                buttonChild: GOAL TO ENTER TITLE HERE,
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedWeight = Weight.adjusted;
                  });
                },
                bgColor: selectedWeight == Weight.adjusted
                    ? Colors.orange[600]
                    : Colors.grey[600],
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: can't you just add two more RectButtons to your row?

Comment: I do have two other buttons (left them off to save space in the above example) but it won't let me insert a title for the RectButton when I implement it into the TriButton class. I cant figure out how to grant properties to the RectButton so that I can customize it in the TriButton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using a StatefulWidget you need to use "widget.property" in your implementation.

In your case

```
 Expanded(
              child: RectButton(
                buttonChild: Text(widget.title1),
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedWeight = Weight.adjusted;
                  });
                },
                bgColor: selectedWeight == Weight.adjusted
                    ? Colors.orange[600]
                    : Colors.grey[600],
              ),
            ),
 Expanded(
              child: RectButton(
                buttonChild: Text(widget.title2),
                onPress: () {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedWeight = Weight.adjusted;
                  });
                },
                bgColor: selectedWeight == Weight.adjusted
                    ? Colors.orange[600]
                    : Colors.grey[600],
              ),
            ),
```

.....

Comment: Rleffler thanks for your help! When I try to utilize the "widget.property" method, I am getting the error, "The argument type 'String' cant be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget'"